# How to map a static external IP to static internal IP on Apple Airport extreme

Tags: airport

I am trying to enable external VNC access to a Mac mini on a small network. I have a static IP address (67.41.xxx.xxx) reserved through my internet provider and the Mac mini has a reserved IP 172.16.5.9. How can I setup Apple Airport Extreme through Airport Utility (software v 6.1) to route traffic from the external IP to the internal IP?

Thanks

Comment: AirPort Utility > Manual Setup > Internet > NAT > Enable default host at: 172.16.5.9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a utility called [Port Map](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) to do this. It allows you to manually make the same calls things like Facetime and iChat do to map ports for file transfers, etc. It's free, simple, kid tested, mother approved.